# Using Highcharts, how to change background color of Treemap Chart according to the colors in my column?

Tags: r, highcharts, r-highcharter

How can I change the background color of this Treemap Chart according to the colors in my `colors` column of my highchart in R/Shiny?

This is my code:

```
library(highcharter)
library(tidyverse)
library(gapminder)
library("RColorBrewer")

colors <- c(brewer.pal(n = 9, name = "Greens"),
            brewer.pal(n = 11, name = "BrBG"),
            brewer.pal(n = 5, name = "RdBu"))



data <- gapminder::gapminder %>%
  dplyr::filter(year  == 2007, continent == 'Americas') %>% mutate(colors = colors)


data %>%


  highcharter::data_to_hierarchical(group_vars = c(continent, country),

                                    size_var = pop) %>%
  hchart(type = "treemap",colorByPoint = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
data %>%
  highcharter::data_to_hierarchical(group_vars = c(continent, country),
                                    size_var = pop) %>%
  hchart(type = "treemap",colorByPoint = TRUE) %>% 
  hc_colors(colors = colors)
```

[image]